# Swift: How to match ranged values (NSRange) array with full names Strings array?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, algorithm, range

**Problem:**

I have a comment string like = "@Scott Winburn and @Ben Bloodworth and @Alex Gonzalez and @Jerry Anderson"

I have 2 arrays:

1. that gets the full names = ["@Scott Winburn", "@Ben Bloodworth", "@Alex Gonzalez", "@Jerry Anderson"] = `getMentionContactsFromComment()`
2. that gets the ranged values for each full name = [{0, 14}, {19, 15}, {39, 14}, {58, 15}] = `setRangedMentionContactValues()`

**Desired Output:**

// if rangedValue == FullName range { // do something }

**I'm trying to match those ranged values (in order, cuz the ranged values and full names match the order) with it's associated full name range:**

Note: I have to drop the "@" symbol for each name.

I've also tried putting `NSRange(location: rangedMentionValue.location, length: totalMentionName.count)`

BUT IT FAILS/
BUT if I print the ranged MentionValue.location and tap on the names it return correctly but prints two values (0) (0) (39) (39) etc.

**How to make these values match up from the two arrays?**

**What I've tried:**

```
     for rangedMentionValue in setRangedMentionContactValues() {
        for mentionName in getMentionContactsFromComment() {
          let newMentionName = mentionName.dropFirst()
          let totalMentionName = String(newMentionName)
        
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: rangedMentionValue) {
          if rangedMentionValue == NSRange(location: rangedMentionValue.lowerBound, length: totalMentionName.count) { // contact name range 14
//            print("Tapped \(mentionName) with \(rangedMentionValue)")
          }
        }
```

**If I hard code it it, and take it out of the for loop with mentionNames, WORKS how I want for each unique tap on a name like this (I need it dynamic not hard coded), BUT I need the name also dynamic and not hard coded too like this:**

```
    @objc func tappedOnLabel(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      
//      for value in getMentionContactsFromComment() {
//        print(value)
//      }
      
      for rangedValue in setRangedMentionContactValues() {
        
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: rangedValue) {
            if rangedValue == NSRange(location: 0, length: 14) { // contact name range
              print("Tapped Scott Winburn with \(rangedValue)") = "Tapped Scott Winburn { 0, 14 }"
            }
          }

          if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: rangedValue) {
            if rangedValue == NSRange(location: 19, length: 15) { // contact name range
              print("Tapped Ben BloodWorth with \(rangedValue)") = "Tapped Ben BloodWorth with { 19, 15 }"
            }
          }

          if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: rangedValue) {
            if rangedValue == NSRange(location: 39, length: 14) { // contact name range
              print("Tapped Alex Gonzalez with \(rangedValue)") = "Tapped Alex Gonzalez with { 39, 14 }"
            }
          }
      }

**Part 1 of the problem solved: Tapping the correct ranges for each name and printing.. but Part 2 of how to get the name from that tapped range:**
    @objc func tappedOnLabel(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      // get contactNames for selected cell
      // for each contactName
      // get contactName range
      // condition to equal a single contactName range
      // if value ==  the contactName range [one of these values of ranges (0, 14) (19, 15) (39, 14) (58, 15)]
      // set the contact name
      // set mentionTapped = true
//      for value in getMentionContactsFromComment() {
//        print(value)
//      }
      
      for rangedValue in setRangedMentionContactValues() {
        
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: rangedValue) {
          if rangedValue == NSRange(location: rangedValue.location, length: rangedValue.length) { // contact name range
              print("Tapped correct name with \(rangedValue)")
            }
          }
      }
      
    }
```

Well, @bewithyou solved it by saying I need to map in a dictionary:

```
      for (mentionName, mentionRange) in zip(getMentionContactsFromComment(), setRangedMentionContactValues()) {
//        print("\(mentionName) : \(mentionRange)")
        
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: mentionRange) {
          if mentionRange == NSRange(location: mentionRange.location, length: mentionName.count) {
            let newMentionName = String(mentionName.dropFirst())
            print(newMentionName)
          }
        }
        
      }
```

Comment: Do not use integer based ranges with strings in Swift. There is `Range<String.Index>`.

Comment: Yes, but you can't do that here.. for example: Range<String.Index> like with a mention name:  mentionName.startIndex...mentionName.endIndex, there's no way I can find to get that into an NSRange.  Plus this works too good with pin point precision hard coded, need it dynamic.

Comment: There is an initializer `NSRange(_:in:)`. The first parameter is a `Range<String.Index>` instance, the second one the affected string.

Comment: Unfortunately, those intializers failed each time, hence the awesome zip function in Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This credit goes to @bewithyou for sure:

```
  for (mentionName, mentionRange) in zip(getMentionContactsFromComment(), setRangedMentionContactValues()) {
```

//        print("(mentionName) : (mentionRange)")

```
    if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: mentionRange) {
      if mentionRange == NSRange(location: mentionRange.location, length: mentionName.count) {
        let newMentionName = String(mentionName.dropFirst())
        print(newMentionName)
      }
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you compare the name after you drop "@" on the first index; then you get the lenght of it; after that compare to the range with contains "@" from the beginning. That's the reason I think you dynamic func not working.

Try to change it like below

```swift
for rangedMentionValue in setRangedMentionContactValues() {
    for mentionName in getMentionContactsFromComment() {
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: parent.label, inRange: rangedMentionValue) {
            if rangedMentionValue == NSRange(location: rangedMentionValue.lowerBound, length: mentionName.count) {
                let newMentionName = String(mentionName.dropFirst())

                break // break the loop after finding the right
                // you can use return here if you want to exit func immediately too
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is so close that will print the newMentionName as:

Tapped correct name with {0, 14}
Scott Winburn

Tapped correct name with {0, 14}
Alex Gonzalez

So I need to just get the first result

Comment: Dear @ScottW, adding ``break`` or ``return`` when you get the result. That's all you need. Check update answer of my post

Comment: we are on the same wavelength, I tried break at the same spot you have it, but will only return first two names tapped:

{39, 14} should be Alex Gonzalez, not Scott Winburn again..
same with { 58, 15 } should be Jerry Anderson, not Ben BloodWorth again..

Comment: That's the reason you should have a dictionary which mapping the name with range at first not seperate it like this. Then it will work ok because each word will have thier own start location. You just need format input first

Comment: That definitely answered the question <br>
for (word, number) in zip(getMentionContactsFromComment(), setRangedMentionContactValues()) {
        print("\(word) : \(number)")
      }

Scott Winburn : {0, 14}
Ben Bloodworth : {19, 15}
Alex Gonzalez : {39, 14}
Jerry Anderson : {58, 15}